# How to get lyrics from the Deezer API?

Tags: deezer

Is it possible to get lyric info for a track from the Deezer api?

I'm looking for time-tagged data for a karaoke app. The deezer site itself clearly has this available and makes use of it to show karaoke-style lyrics, so the data and access exist, but it's not described anywhere in the [api documentation](http://developers.deezer.com/api).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the lyrics are not available on our REST API.

Comment: Why - is this a technical issue that might get fixed (and if so, is it on your roadmap?), or a legal/business constraint that's not going away?

Comment: We are investigating how to set that in our roadmap but I can not give any ETA now.

Comment: Is there any update for lyrics on Deezer?

Answer (score 4):

They actually do have an API, but it's hidden. You will need a basic understanding of searching Deezer first (which is easy as hell), once you can search for a song and get the ID from that search, use

https://www.deezer.com/ajax/gw-light.php?method=song.getLyrics&api_version=1.0&api_token=[api-token]&sng_id=[song-id]

To get your API key, you can use inspect element on deezer.com. Open Inspect > Network > reload the page > click on (most likely) the second entry > scroll down to "Query String Parameters" > copy api_token and use that in the link above.

The docs for the Deezer search API can also be found [here](https://developers.deezer.com/api/search).

Comment: When I did this, I found multiple API tokens, none of which seemed to work with this request. Does this still work?